# Community Goal: 5 QPD by end of the year

Tags: discussion, statistics

We're below 2 [QPD](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4059/musical-practice-and-performance). I don't want to see this site closed. My goal is to raise the QPD stat to 5 by Dec 31, 2012. When this site first got out of Private Beta, everyone involved got an email saying :

> Tell all your friends, blog about it, tweet about it, and write the URL (http://history.stackexchange.com) in chalk on the sidewalk in front of your neighbor's house. Or paint. No, never mind, better use chalk.

It's not too late to do that again. When you visit other forums, promote Music SE. When your garage band gets together next week, tell them all about it. When you get your first winter snow, draw the URL on the ground in front of your neighbor's house. We must promote this site. It is essential to raising the QPD stat. That's the only stat that we still have to raise to get out of beta. So close, yet so far. Let's give it the gusto for the last lap before graduation!

Comment: How high will it really have to go before we can graduate? And how long will we have to sustain that level?

Comment: 15 is the "excellent" level. However, I've seen sites (such as Bikes and Skeptics) that graduate with a lower level than that, however. But, we're not graduating at two. It takes at least five.

Comment: I want to help by asking more, but at the same time I feel like I'm just asking questions here, and there aren't enough that I feel expert enough to answer. Maybe others are having the same issue?

Comment: I sometimes have the same feeling, but if I have a legit on-topic question that I want to know the answer to, nothing's going to stop me from asking it. If I'm just asking it to seed the site, I probably will eventually decide not to ask. For example, in http://music.stackexchange.com/q/7527/1678, I had been wondering it for a while and seriously wanted to know. Do you see the difference? Don't ask for the sake of seeding the site. Ask to gain knowledge. If you have four times as many questions as answers, that's not great, but if you really want the answers, then go right ahead.